# Python Variable IDs causing problem when defining another variable as itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to enumerate through list d of the dict a and transfer them to list c.

Not working:

```
a = {"c": [], "d": [1, 2, 3]}

b = a

for index, value in enumerate(a["d"]):
    print(value)
    b["c"].append(b["d"].pop(b["d"].index(value)))
    print(b)
```

Output:

```
1
{'c': [1], 'd': [2, 3]}
3
{'c': [1, 3], 'd': [2]}
```

Working:

```
a = {"c": [], "d": [1, 2, 3]}

b = {"c": [], "d": [1, 2, 3]} # <- Changed to the exact same dict

for index, value in enumerate(a["d"]):
    print(value)
    b["c"].append(b["d"].pop(b["d"].index(value)))
    print(b)
```

Output:

```
1
{'c': [1], 'd': [2, 3]}
2
{'c': [1, 2], 'd': [3]}
3
{'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': []}
```

So why is only the second one working?

Comment: Hmm, the "not working" output looks better than the "working" one...

Comment: Outputs need to be **swapped**. I ran code on my machine and the outputs are different than indicated.

Comment: omg, im so sorry, at this point i was just confused and i forgot to check it. my fault

Answer (score 0):

Your first code has a single dictionary, and its address is saved in both `a` and `b` variables. So `a["c"]` is the same list as `b["c"]`, and `a["d"]` is the same list as `b["d"]`.

Then you start iterating on the list `a["d"]`. In the first iteration, the index is `0`, and you pop the value `1` as `b["d"][0]` which is the same as `a["d"][0]`. Notice that now the value `2` is located in the index `0`, and you will never iterate on it. In the second iteration, the index is `1`, and you pop the value `3` which is now located in the index `1`.

Your second code has two separate independent dictionaries. Their addresses are stored in variables `a` and `b`. Also, you have four independent lists (`a["c"]`, `a["d"]`, `b["c"]`, and `b["d"]`). You are iterating on `a["d"]`, but you pop items from `b["d"]` which is another list. So, when you pop an element from `b["d"]`, that element does still exist in `b["a"]`, and doesn't make any change in your iteration.

In your first code, the loop iterates 2 times to reach the end of the list (because you are deleting elements from the list), but in the second code, the loop iterates 3 times.

Answer (score -3):

```
a = {"c": [], "d": [1, 2, 3]}
b = {"c": [], "d": [1, 2, 3]} # <- Changed to the exact same dict
a['c'].append(a['d'])
a['d']=[]
print(a)
```

Comment: It has to iterate through all items in the list one by one.